# Retrieve mutiple XML nodes with the same level name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that retrieves some data out of a XML document. I was only after 1 specific result each time but now I ran into some isues where there are multiple levels (elt in picture) with the same name. 
I need to return all the NameId/text() values. The code I am using now only returns the first result.

The code I am using:

```
Set Test2 = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/Report/Results/NameListId/elt/NameId/text()")
NameId = Test2(i).NodeValue
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the value of `i` ?

Comment: can you paste the actual xml string?

Comment: If i put `for i = 0 to 20` before it, it will indeed return me all separate values but then it will return 16 times the last result (in this example)

Comment: @Scott the actuall string contains confidential information, that is why I made a dummy example

Comment: do a `For Each` loop: `For Each nmId in Test2`  Then `NameId = nmId`

Comment: `Test2.Length` tells you how many nodes in your list.

Comment: Great that does the trick: `For i = 0 To Test2.Length - 1` The  `for each` didn't work, it only returned the first node.